# Angularjs promise this references window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I've made a basemodel with a load function, defined below:

```
    BaseModel.prototype.load = function(id) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    var self = this;
                    Db.getById(this.getTableName(), id).then(function(data) {
                        deferred.resolve(new BaseModel(data));
//self has a reference to window here
                    }, function(err) {
                        deferred.reject(null);
                    });

                return deferred.promise;
            };
```

In my child class which derives from this basemodel im calling it with:

```
return BaseModel.prototype.load.call(this, id);
```

But in the 'success' part of promise the 'var' self has a reference to the window... Is it possible to keep a reference to my object and if so, how? I can't find an example for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`return BaseModel.prototype.load.call(this, id);` <-- This line is your problem. I am not exactly sure what you are doing there, but from what I am seeing, **you are setting** the `this` value using `call`, which probably at that point of code, points to `Window` object.

If your child object of `BaseModel` is say `childObj`. That line can simply be:

```
return childObj.load(id);
```